# In $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ what inputs can X take?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

In the polynomial rings $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ or more generally $R[X]$ what inputs can we put in the place of X.

For example in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$. X can be replaced by any real or complex numbers.

But in general can we put any member of any set in the place of X ?

Comment: Technically, you can replace $X$ by anything, if you consider $f \in \mathbf{Z}[X]$ as function $f : \text{whatever} \to \text{whatever}$ (as long as "whatever" has polynomial operations; see the answers). The only thing "$f \in \mathbf{Z}[X]$" says, is that $f$ is a polynomial with integer coefficients. But you can of course, for example, consider the same $f$ as function $\mathbf{C} \to \mathbf{C}$, or something.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In $R[X]$, $X$ is an indeterminate, i.e. a symbolic variable.
When you say you "put" some $x$ in place of $X$, you're talking about the mapping
$f_x: \sum_i r_i X^i \mapsto \sum_i r_i x^i$.
If $R$ is a commutative ring and $x$ a member of some commutative ring $S$ that contains $R$, this is a ring homomorphism of $R[X]$ into $S$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ be a ring with unit, which need not be commutative. Let $a \in A$. Then there is a unique ring homomorphism $\mathbb{Z}[X] \to A$ such that $X \mapsto a$. This homomorphism is of course given by $f(X) \mapsto f(a)$, suitably interpreted. That is, $nb = b + b + \cdots + b$ ($n$ times) for $n \in \mathbb N$ and  $b \in A$.

Bottom line: you may put in the place of $X$ any object for which you know how to multiply by itself and add to itself. One prime example is square matrices with entries in a ring.

For general coefficient rings $R$, all you need is a ring homomorphism $\phi: R \to A$ such that $\phi(r)$ commutes with $a$ for all $r \in R$. One common condition is this direction is to require that $\phi(R)$ is contained in the center of $A$. This effectively makes $A$ into an $R$-algebra. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_algebra#From_ring_homomorphisms).